# MySQL dump import seems to be paused

Tags: mysql, import, wamp, wampserver, mysql-5.7

After many failed attempts to import a huge 1.2 GB database to my local database over Phpmyadmin I gave up and tried a MySQL console solution.

I started my console via the wampserver tray menu and entered following commands:

```
> use my_database
> source path/to/my/dump.sql
```

It worked perfectly fine for about half a minute, then it stopped working and it is still at the same spot for more than 30 minutes.

[image]

These are my MySQL settings:

[image]

Does it fail yet again or should I wait?

---

The version of both MySQL servers is the same (`5.7.21`)

Comment: Do you see anything useful in the mysql error log

Comment: Or the windows event log

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I just checked it, there is absolutely nothing helpful.

Comment: You might try breaking down the backup file  and running it in pieces

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I guess I will have to do that. I noticed that it always stops at `97,7 MiB` database size

Comment: Of course there could be an error in the backup file. Specially if it was dumped on a different version of MySQL  than is being used to restore it

Comment: Then why is the error not shown?

Comment: These are the mysteries of development. Sometimes odd things happen

Comment: @Black if an error is occurring, you should definitely get an error.  Running the query `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` from another connection will show you the status of current connections, one of which should be the restore process.

Comment: Since dump is loaded via phpMyAdmin you can also look at web server logs for php-related errors. phpMyAdmin was never good at huge dumps loading.